# IOS/xcode/objective-C: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification error trying to save to core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am getting the following error when trying to save to the managed object context:

```
    2015-09-09 20:07:58.956 idaru[13803:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error. 
 Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually 
a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -
[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument with userInfo (null)

    2015-09-09 20:07:58.959 idaru[13803:60b] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -
[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2f5f7fd3 0x39e70ccf 0x2f5f7f15 0x2ff37af9 0x2ff3d3bf 0x11bc2f 0x11a5b1 0x11b443 0x2f37090b 0x2f5ba1f1 0x2f52e53f 0x2ff18a3d 0x2f36f9c3 0x2f36f95b 0x2f36dfc3 0x2f36ccc7 0x133ea5 0x31e49057 0x31fafc65 0x31e49057 0x31e48ff7 0x31e48fd1 0x31e34737 0x31e48a4f 0x31e48721 0x31e436eb 0x31e188ed 0x31e16f97 0x2f5c325b 0x2f5c272b 0x2f5c0f1f 0x2f52bf0f 0x2f52bcf3 0x34484663 0x31e7716d 0x15f3b1 0x3a37dab7)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If I remove the actual lines in the save that change the managed object context, the error disappears though of course nothing gets saved.  Otherwise, I get a sigbart error plus above in log.

My app has many identical save methods that are working fine and this was working at one point. Somehow, something went awry.

Has anyone seen this before and/or can provide suggestion on what is wrong?

The save method is very long but the gist of it is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Begin saving edit");
    self.managedObjectContext = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    // Helpers

    NSString *name = self.textField.text;
    if (name && name.length) {
            // Populate Record
       [self.person setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
           // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Dismiss View Controller
            NSLog(@"About to dismiss modal editVC");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
             else {

                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"Unable to save record.");
                     NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);

                 // Show Alert View
                     }

             } else {
//no name Show Alert View
                      }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a tableView somewhere showing this data?

Comment: Not in this view controller.  However, there is a tableview for this set of records originally.  Then each row segues to a detail view.  This is the edit view of the detail.

Comment: That error looks like an error I have seen when NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods are not implemented correctly- not sure in this case but you might want to check if you are using these methods as they will be called if you make any changes to the underlying objects.

Comment: Found error after days of agony.  It was in the tableViewController.  I was thrown off because it only occurred when the edit detail controller tried to access the managed object context.  But evidently, behind the scenes this triggered the NSFetchedResults controller back in the tableview.  The error was that in - (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
I was testing f (![[object valueForKey:@"name"] description])  when it should have been for pic.  Not sure why this matters but in any case problem is solved.  Thx for tableview suggestions.